# Error in installing native base in my project

Tags: node.js, npm

In my project I used to install npm native base using the command **npm install native-base**

but it is showing some errors as like this.

**Error**

up to date, audited 986 packages in 7s

39 packages are looking for funding

run `npm fund` for details

17 vulnerabilities (12 moderate, 5 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:

npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

How can we fix this error??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).